# CUDA: "Stack Overflow or Breakpoint Hit" and unspecified launch failure error after copying char array from host to device

Tags: c, cuda, stack-overflow, unspecified-behavior

I have a large char array in my main program that I copy in chunks to the device
memory. I run about 500,000 threads in my program and each thread accesses 2000 chars.
So I transfer 500,000 * 2000 = 1GB bytes at a time with the code

```
err = cudaMemcpy (dev_database, adjusted_database[k], JOBS * 2000 * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if(err != cudaSuccess) { printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err)); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

In my kernel I also define three **shared** arrays

```
//__shared__ char dev_query[200];
__shared__ float dev_scores[200*5];
__shared__ int dev_index[26];
```

and initialize them with

```
if(threadIdx.x == 0) { 
  //for(i = 0; i < 200; i++){ dev_query[i] = dev_query_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 200 * 5; i++){ dev_scores[i] = dev_scores_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){ dev_index[i] = dev_index_constant[i]; }
}
__syncthreads();
```

If I run my program with the two lines commented my kernel returns strange 
values and when I copy the second chunk of the char array I get the error

CUDA error: unspecified launch failure

If I uncomment the lines in the code above everything works fine. If I copy smaller
chunks of the array, such as 100MB instead of 1GB, its works fine until I get to the 
6th chunk where I get the same errors as above.

This is very strange behaviour and I'd like to understand why is this happening. Is
there a bug somewhere that is causing this? It's hard to pinpoint it because the
program works fine if I transfer a small chunk (such as 100MB) and ignore the other
ones. It also works fine if I uncomment the lines related to the shared variables
or change the shared variables to constant.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is my kernel. To summarize, I'm computing the similarity score of two 
strings by comparing their ith character for all i between 0 and their lengths. 
This code below will produce the above error
unless you uncomment the line immediately after  `if(threadIdx.x == 0) {`. Or if you
replace the shared arrays below with constant ones then it also works fine.

```
__global__ void assign7(int jobs_todo, char* database, float* results, int flag) {
unsigned int id = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

if(id < jobs_todo) {
__shared__ char dev_query[200];
__shared__ float dev_pos_specific_scores[200*5];
__shared__ int dev_subst_index[26];

int j_, i, p, stop, k; //stop2;
float score=0, max=0;
char ch; //ch1, ch2;

if(threadIdx.x == 0) {
//for(i = 0; i < 51; i++){ dev_query[i] = dev_query_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 5 * 200; i++){ dev_pos_specific_scores[i] = dev_pos_specific_scores_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){ dev_subst_index[i] = dev_subst_index_constant[i]; }
}
__syncthreads(); 

for(i = 1; i <= 2000 - 51; i += 1){
  p = jobs_todo*(i-1);
  score = 0;
  stop = 51/1; stop = stop*1;
  for(j_ = 1; j_ <= stop; j_ += 1){
    k = (j_-1)*5;
    ch = database[p + id];
    score += dev_pos_specific_scores[k + dev_subst_index[ch - 'A']];
    if(score < 0) score = 0;
    if(score > max) max = score;                                      
    p += jobs_todo;
  }
}
results[id] = max;
}
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of your kernel do? Are you using recursion?

Comment: I'm not using recursion. The rest of the code is a for loop. I'll post some of it here after this comment.

Comment: My question now has my kernel code. I call this from my main program after copying a char array to the device memory from the host.

Comment: That's a lot of code to debug in a web browser.  I recommend you use the old technique of commenting it all out, running, uncommenting a little, running again, etc. until you narrow down the cause.

Comment: Could you document the execution arguments (block and grid size) and n for the failed cuda-memcheck case you have posted? Also, am I right in presuming that the source memory for the code you think causes the problem is device `__constant__` memory?

Comment: @talonmies I am running 1954 blocks and 256 threads which gives 500,224 threads in total. I think the problem lies in the shared memory. I say this because if I convert the shared memory variables dev_query, dev_scores, and dev_index to constant then I don't get the memory errors but am 1.5 times slower. If I leave them as shared then it runs fine as long as I uncomment the line immediately after if threadIdx.x == 0. I don't need dev_query for my program and don't use it anywhere else as you can see in the code. It is only there because I was experimenting with different algorithms earlier.

Comment: @harrism if you comment the lines `if(score > max) max = score; if(score2 > max) max = score2; if(score3 > max) max = score3; if(score4 > max) max = score4; if(score5 > max) max = score5;` right at the bottom of the code then I don't get the memory errors if `__shared__ dev_query` is commented. ptxas info shows that my kernel uses just 3 registers in this case. However, I need those lines for my algorithm to produce useful output.

Comment: At the beginning you commented out a loop that defines `i` and then you use `i` uninitialized.  Is that the problem or a mistake in pasting the code here?

Comment: @harrism I'm not sure if I follow your comment above. I believe i is defined in the beginning. In any case, I have a much shorter version of my kernel that has the memory problem. I'll update my code above in a while tonight.

Comment: Hmmm, the code appears to be different from when I posted that comment.

Comment: @harrism I haven't changed it since 11 hours ago.

Comment: I may have found the problem. The index of dev_index becomes -1 when ch < 'A'. I wasn't expecting this in my data but I just found a ch that causes this to happen. The code is fine. It's the data. Thanks @harrism for your comments.

Comment: @harrism I spoke too soon. It's not the index of dev_index that becomes -1 but the value of dev_index[ch-'A'] that returns -1. That is fine. Even after fixing the data I'm getting the same memory errors. It has something to do with shared memory because if I change the shared variables to constant it works fine. I've posted a shorter version of my source that still fails.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8365/discussion-between-ross-and-harrism)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some characters in the data that caused `dev_index[ch-'A']` to return -1. This
made the index of `dev_scores` -1 when k = 0. I believe that was the source of the
memory error in my code. I commented everything and incrementally uncommented portions.
It works fine now. Thanks @talonmies, @harrism, and @perreal for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

The part below uses `k` without initializing it:

```
ch = database[p + id];
score += dev_scores[k + dev_index[ch - 'A']];
```

This is irrelevant but this part:

```
if(threadIdx.x == 0) { 
  //for(i = 0; i < 200; i++){ dev_query[i] = dev_query_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 200 * 5; i++){ dev_scores[i] = dev_scores_constant[i]; }
  for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){ dev_index[i] = dev_index_constant[i]; }
}
```

can be changed to something like:

```
if(threadIdx.x < 200) {
  // dev_query[i] = dev_query_constant[i];
}

if(threadIdx.x < 200 * 5) { // or iterate whole block 5 times..
  dev_scores[i] = dev_scores_constant[i];
}
...
```

Comment: I didn't think of this. It's clever. Thanks.

Comment: The k is a typo that I have now corrected. Instead of k it should say (j_-1)*5.